# Linking to another page when post is clicked php

Tags: php, mysql

I am not looking for the code, but I am wondering how I would go about solving this issue. I have a simple site where a user submits form data that is stored on a database and then what they wrote is displayed on the mainpage each post in its own section. What would be need to make it is I can click on a post on the main page and be directed to a page displaying only that post so it would be like example.com/posts.php?id=$postId. What is the best way to go about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should accomplish what you want. 
Sending Id of a post via a GET method should be simple and safe.
You can use that `$_GET['id']` and display the post content as required

Also, in the posts.php ( or any other file ), when you detect a `$_GET['id']`, 
make sure you check the database if there's a post with that id. If there's not you could just display a gentle error message so that the user is not confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it several ways. I would go with a simple link..

`echo '<a href="example.com/posts.php?id="'.$postId.'">Link Name</a>';`

Comment: But would that be creating a new page each time. I am looking to just click on the post and view it in another screen that seems to imply the linking page has been made already

Comment: To open another window just add the HTML attribute `"target='_blank'"`

Comment: No, it doesn't create a new page. It just opens the existing posts.php page.

Comment: And then from there I would query the database to get the post?

Comment: Correct, using the superglobal `$_GET['id']` to grab the parameter from the URL

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
echo '<a href="URL.php?id=".$postId.">Link Name</a>';
```